# How do I download all photos in bulk from Facebook

Tags: automation, facebook

What I would like to do is to download all the pictures:

- I have uploaded
- I am tagged in

The way offered by Facebook itself seems to allow only to download pictures in low resolution format (this method: https://www.facebook.com/help/1701730696756992), what I would like to do is to download them in **full resolution**.

Is there a way to do it in bulk? 
Is there a way to automate this task somehow? (with greasemonkey, or other browser extensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request to download all your Facebook information.

You can find this on `Settings > Your Facebook Information > Download Your Information`.

Deselect all and select Photos and Videos.

This will include all your photos and you can set the media quality to High.

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked. 
This must be a new implementation, as it wasn't downloading the full-resolution pictures in the past. It's been a nice surprise :D